# How to delete a line by passing line number as variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to delete a line of a document by passing the number as variable, like so:

```
ERR=`set of bash commands` ;  sed '${ERR}d' file
```

However the above sed command in single quotes does not work. How to achieve this task then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a given file like

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and your variable containing the line number like

```
$ ERR=5
```

#### Using `sed`:

Use **double quote** to allow the variable to interpolate. Notice the use of curly braces to allow `sed` to differentiate between variable and `d` flag. In the output line number 5 is no longer printer.

```
$ sed "${ERR}d" file
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
```

#### Using `awk`:

`NR` stores the line number for a given file. Passing the shell variable to `awk` using `-v` option we create an `awk` variable called `no`. Using the condition where `NR` is not equal to our `awk` variable we tell `awk` to print everything except the line number we don't want to print.

```
$ awk -v no="$ERR" 'NR!=no' file
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to ask if two separate lines, for example, line 3rd and 5th, are needed to be deleted, what is the command?

Comment: @BinhThien You can string sed commands with a semicolon: `sed "3d;5d"` deletes the 3rd and 5th lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is nice (The Good, the Bad and the Ugly—Clint Eastwood, Lee Van Cleef, and Eli Wallach):

```
good='1680790311' #the Good;
bad=2 #the Bad;
ugly=1 #the Ugly;
deleteYesExists=$(grep -n "$good" userdb.tmp | cut -d':' -f1);
if [[ $deleteYesExists > 0 ]];then sed -i "$deleteYesExists"d userdb.tmp;fi
```

and too:

```
if [[ $(grep -n "$good" userdb.tmp | cut -d':' -f1) = "$ugly" ]];then sed -i "$bad"d userdb.tmp;fi
```